# JS Update Canvas Animation every X seconds

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am trying to make a simple clock using Canvas but I am having trouble updating the animation, I have tried to use the `setInterval` function but it's not working for some reason. I want to update my clock every 500ms or 1s for example.

What am I doing wrong?

```
var draw = function() {
    secondsMask.draw();
    seconds.draw();
    minutesMask.draw();
    minutes.draw();
    hoursMask.draw();
    hours.draw();
};

setInterval(draw(), 500);
```

http://pastebin.com/nut72Fcb

Answer (score 3):

`draw` is a function you need to call later not now, and `setInterval` needs a function as first parameter.

Therefore, change this

```
setInterval(draw(), 500);
```

To this

```
setInterval(draw, 500);
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked somehow. It is executing the code now I added a console.log in the draw function so that I can see it in the console if it really works, and it does! But my animation is not updating it just stays there, I need to refresh to get the new values of the time - the new radiuses of the circles.... How do I fix that?